# How to override an objects dot access for a specific column in Django?

Tags: python, django

Say I have a Django object that I have filtered like so:

```
details_obj = DetailsTable.objects.get(user_name='nap')

details_obj.user_name
'nap'

details_obj.city
'Paris'

details_obj.age
22
```

Now what I want to do is override the access for one specific column to achieve something like:

```py
# if a new city exists in a different table
if updated_city_exists:
    # return the updated city instead
    return 'London'
else:
    # the usual flow that currently exists in Django
    return obj.city 

# is user accesses city like
details_obj.city
'London' 
# London returned here as updated city exists for this user
```

I can't really modify the model of the existing `DetailsTable` due to it being pre-existing code that has been used a lot of times.

Also there are lots of places in the code where dot access for city is already taking place. So I would like to override the existing method to access the column value.

I also don't want to update the `city` column in the existing `DetialsTable` column.

Is there anyway I can achieve this? The only thing I could think of was to write a function would return updated city if it exists and use this function everywhere but I will have to replace a lot of existing code if I do this.

Comment: What do you mean by `if a new city exists in a different table` ?

Answer (score 1):

In your model

```
@property
def updated_city(self):
    # if a new city exists in a different table
    if updated_city_exists:
        # return the updated city instead
        return 'London'
    # the usual flow that currently exists in Django
    return obj.city
```

Now `details_obj.updated_city` will return the city according to your logic in `def updated_city`.